# get only featured image

Tags: wordpress, attachment

I search internet, but I found only the reverse scenerio, the thing I want to do is that get only featured image in this query

```
$attachments = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_parent__in' => $published,
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'fields' => 'ids',
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'orderby' => 'rand',
                'update_post_term_cache' => false,
                'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
                'no_found_rows' => true
            ) );

            if ( $attachments->have_posts() ) {
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachments->posts[0], $args[ 'size' ] );

                if ( file_exists( $image[0] ) ) {
                    set_transient( $objects_key, $image, 3 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the end goal?

Comment: to get only featured image...

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail ?? You need to be a lot clearer about what you want - and you really should not use WP_Query for a general query let alone for getting images

Comment: mate its function to get all attachments of a post, the thing I want to do is to include only featured image not all attachments...

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id will get the featured image for either the current post or for the post id you provide it - or are you wishing to parse an array of post ids?

Comment: Sorry, I m not a big developer mate the only thing i know is that this part of code is getting attachments from post including featured image, $attachments->posts[0], but I only want to get feaured image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to mess with wp_query() if you can help it try this...

```
global $post;
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
if($post_thumbnail_id != null) {
  $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, $args[ 'size' ] );
  if ( file_exists( $image[0] ) ) {
    set_transient( $objects_key, $image, 3 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
  }
}
```

I am asuming that $objects_key and HOUR_IN_SECONDS are defined elsewhere